# Add to list mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, razor, collections

I'm trying to add string data to list, but have null reference exception and don't have any idea how to fix this.

Here home controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ChatUser model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        **model.chatGroup.Add(model.inputGroups);**  - here excepton 
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And Index.cshtml:

```
@model test.Models.ChatUser
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.inputGroups, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.inputGroups, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <input type="submit" value="GO" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>


}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialize your list of the model `model.chatGroup` I think it's a `List<string> chatGroup` from your model. You have to initialize it

Comment: Sorry missed to add that, but it's already initialized. public List<string> chatGroup { get; set; }

Comment: It's not enough declaring the list to initialize it, do it like this `model.chatGroup = new List<string>();` (model.chatGroup because you are trying to add the string when you are receiving the post)

Comment: Did you try to debug and ensure that obvious objects, like chatGroup, is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form does not include any controls for properties of `chatGroup` so its `null` when you post back. You need to either initialize the property in a parameterless constructor

```
public class ChatUser
{
  public ChatUser()
  {
    chatGroup = new List<string>(); // initialize collection
  }
  ....
  public List<string> chatGroup { get; set; }
}
```

or initialize it in the POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ChatUser model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    model.chatGroup = new List<string>(); // initialize collection
    model.chatGroup.Add(model.inputGroups);
  }
  return View(model);
}
```